# What new things need to be covered in Embedded Systems testing compared to normal manual testing?

Tags: test-design, learning, embedded

Can you provide me with some common checklist for Embedded Systems testing please? What are the new things that are covered in this?

And can you also advise me some interesting references for reading and understanding Embedded Systems testing? It can be books, blogs, articles, etc. such as:

- http://www.applabs.com/html/embedded-systems-testing.html
- http://www.calsoftlabs.com/product-testing/embedded-system-testing.html
- http://www.systematic-testing.com/documents/qualityweek2001_paper.pdf
- http://www.vectorcast.com/

Answer (score 3):

Testing embedded system is basically the same as testing any other system.
The differences are mainly the diversity of the environments, UIs, debug methods etc.
A decent book to start with could be *Testing Embedded Software* by Bart Broekman and Edwin Notenboom, ISBN 0321159861.

Answer (score 1):

Some links and papers can be found here

http://www.atomicobject.com/pages/Embedded+Practices